# How to bypass the validation popup on dell support page when submiting the search string using Python and SeleniumWebdriver

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to automate a task where I need to input service tags in the dell support page and extract the laptop information. But sometimes when I try to submit, the webpage shows a validation pop-up and it has a waiting time of 30 seconds

[image]

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to bypass this validation? Here is what I tried.

```
url = 'https://www.dell.com/support/home/en-in'
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
for service_tag in ['JX0JL13', '20M11J3', 'BH7C3M2', '6MYH5S2']:
    driver.get(url)
    input_element = driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value='//*[@id="inpEntrySelection"]')
    input_element.send_keys(service_tag)
    driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value='//*[@id="btn-entry-select"]').click()
    model = driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value='//*[@id="site-wrapper"]/div/div[4]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/h1').text
    print(model)
```

Answer (score 1):

Ran into a very similar issue of Popup occurring every few searches.

Successful way that I found was by using the other search bar, at the top of the page. Have been able to run few hundred serial Numbers without a popup occurring once; have a feeling its trigger is linked to the main search bar.

After the search you can scrape for whatever data you want and then I recommend reloading the landing page and going and doing your next serial number.

[image: Dell Top searchbar]

I've also added a couple** addition option features (using a chrome profile 1 or 2). Might encounter an Access denied page a couple times, but just reload program w/ a different profile does the trick.

** total list is 9 arguments, including loading user_agents for every run - may need to import a couple things like keys and userAgent for all this to work but try first 5 lines of code n see how you go.

```
#iterate through using this
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[id='md-search-input']").send_keys(serial_num_iteration + Keys.RETURN)
#Scrape the data you want here
time.sleep(3)
driver.get(url)

#Adds profile to driver
options.add_argument(r"--user-data-dir=C:\User\userprofile\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data")
options.add_argument(r"--profile-directory=Profile 2")

#Adds extra bits to driver
options.add_argument("windows-size 1400, 900")
options.add_argument(f"user-agent={user_agent}")
options.add_argument("--disabe-blink-features=AutomationControlled")
options.add_argument("disable-infobars")
options.add_experimental_option("useAutomationExtension", False)
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
```

Answer (score 0):

You are seeing the validation pop-up with a waiting time of **30 seconds**

[image: popup]

possibly as the *ChromeDriver* initiated *Chrome Browser* browsing context is geting [detected](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62520191/7429447) as a [bot](/questions/tagged/bot).

---

### Solution

A potential solution would be to keep the *ChromeDriver* synchronized with the [google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome) browsing context inducing [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the desired ***clickable*** elements to turn [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Code block:

  ```
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s, options=options)
  url = 'https://www.dell.com/support/home/en-in'
  for service_tag in ['JX0JL13', '20M11J3', 'BH7C3M2', '6MYH5S2']:
      driver.get(url)
      WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//input[@id="inpEntrySelection"]'))).send_keys(service_tag)
      WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//button[@id="btn-entry-select"]//span'))).click()
      print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.product-support-hero div.product-summary h1"))).text)
  ```
- Console output:

  ```
  Latitude 7400
  Latitude 7420
  Latitude 7480
  Latitude 7490
  ```

Comment: awesome. But you are using the service and options argument in the web driver. Could you tell me what are the services and options you are using? I'm guessing `useAutomationExtension` !!